# jQuery choose only images that contain certain word to be displayed with alt text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want this script to take the h1 "my_heading_class" of page and use it as alt text of my image only if the file contains certain word **"car"** and the pages body is using "my_template". It works but it also chooses and adds the alt the other image on the page that is name **"bike"**. I want only the images containing word **car** to be changed showing the alt text.

```js
$(function() {
  if ($("body").is(".my_template") && $('img[src*="car"]')) {
    $(".my_heading_class").find(function() {
      $(this)
        .find("img")
        .attr("alt", $(this).find("h1").text() + " my additional alt text");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="my_template">
  <h1 class="my_heading_class">I want this to my img alt text</h1>

  <img src="car.jpg" />

  <img src="bike.jpg" />
</body>
```

Comment: You are missing a `.` in `$("my_heading_class")`

Comment: Yes, but this isn't the problem solving the thing I desire.

Answer (score 1):

First you are missing a `.` in your `$("my_heading_class")`

second i've moved `[src*='car']` to be used another place in the image selection.

You can do it like this:

```
$("img[src*='car']")
  .attr("alt", $(this).closest(".my_heading_class").text() + " my additional alt text");
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  if ($("body").is(".my_template")) {
    $("img[src*='car']")
      .attr("alt", $(this).closest(".my_heading_class").text() + " my additional alt text");
  }
});
```

```html
<body class="my_template">
  <h1 class="my_heading_class">I want this to my img alt text</h1>

  <img src="car.jpg" />

  <img src="bike.jpg" />
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @JeremyThille yer I've also just noticed the strange way, I've added another way

Comment: @JeremyThille thanks thought for pointing it out, if you had been 10 sec faster I wouldn't have spotted it before you wrote :)